# way to embed if expressions inside JSX code?

Tags: reactjs

I guess that stuff that goes into a react tag must be a react tag or a string; a function that returns a tag or string; a collection of tag or string or functions that return them.

So the `if` statement here is not valid:

```
return <div> 
        if(something){
           <ProjectType typ={this.state.type} onChange={this.changeType}/>
        }
        And the choice is {type[this.state.type]}
      </div>;
```

So the obvious way is to move that `if` expression into a function `maybe_render` that returns the tag when the condition is met.

```
return <div> 
        maybe_render(something, this.state.type, this.changeType)
        And the choice is {type[this.state.type]}
      </div>;
```

Problem is, some snippets will have lots of calls to functions that have very little logic. Instead of a 5-line snippet, we may have a 5-line snippet with many calls to extremely small functions.

What is a good way to embed `if` expressions inside JSX code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I usually do ternary if statements if there's not much logic or cause for re-use:

```
return (
    <div>
        {doSomething ? something : null}
        Something else
    </div>
);
```